# Bigquery : job is done but job.query_results().total_bytes_processed returns None

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

The following code :

```
import time
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
query = """\
select 3 as x
"""
dataset = client.dataset('dataset_name')
table = dataset.table(name='table_name')
job = client.run_async_query('job_name_76', query)
job.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job.destination = table
job.begin()
retry_count = 100
while retry_count > 0 and job.state != 'DONE':
    retry_count -= 1
    time.sleep(10)
    job.reload()
print job.state
print job.query_results().name
print job.query_results().total_bytes_processed
```

prints :

```
DONE
job_name_76
None
```

I do not understand why `total_bytes_processed` returns `None` because the job is done and the documentation says :

> total_bytes_processed:
>
> Total number of bytes processed by the query.
>
> See
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#totalBytesProcessed
>
> Return type:  int, or NoneType
>
> Returns:  Count generated on the server (None until set by the server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are right. As you can see in the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L306), the current API does not process data regarding bytes processed.

This has been reported in this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3706) and as you can see in this [tseaver's PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/3721/files/a3dcf11ca56d68b0306c3b352fb69fdd12da504a..0cd8fa5128a54ec2cd6f0c3bde591849902d4f58#diff-6339589c9620895430952bab68a12e14R1316) this feature has already been implemented and awaits review /merging so probably we'll have this code in production quite soon.

In the mean time you could get the result from the `_properties` attribute of `job`, like:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
import types
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path/to/key.json'

bc = Client()
query = 'your query'
job = bc.run_async_query('name', query)
job.begin()
wait_job(job)

query_results = job._properties['statistics'].get('query')
```

`query_results` should have the `totalBytesProcessed` you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found out also that `job._properties['statistics']['totalBytesProcessed']` gives me the result.